# Do we have any functions in python that can calculate Z-score for the given p value?

Tags: python, statistics

How to calculate z-score for the given p-value?
Do we have any functions in python that can calculate Z-score for the given p value?

Comment: what did you find in Google?

Answer (score 0):

I guess you could use [Scipy](https://www.scipy.org/) for Python.